# Obtaining indexes and creating an Python-based numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy, indexing

I'm with issues translating Matlab to Python code, specially when it involves matrices / arrays.

Here, I have a 2D `numpy` array called `output` and I am computing a vector of row-major indexes `t_ind` of the elements that are higher than a variable `vmax`:

```
t_ind = np.flatnonzero(output > vmax)
```

Now I'd like to use these indexes to create a matrix based on that. In MATLAB, I could do that directly:

```
output(t_ind) = 2*vmax - output(t_ind);
```

But in Python this does not work.  Specifically, I get an `IndexError` stating that I'm out of bounds.

I tried to figure it out, but the most elegant solution that I could think involves using `np.hstack()` to transform the array into a vector, compare the indexes, collect them in another variable and come back.

Could you shed some light on this?

Comment: Try to include an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with your question.

Comment: Thanks @BiRico, I'll try to do that soon. I forgot to say that the input is a 2D array. I'll check about MCVE.

Comment: I assumed it was at least 2d :), the answer I gave should work for any number of dimensions. You should edit the question to add that the array is 2d and to add an mcve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a 1D array, the use of `np.flatnonzero` is correct.  Specifically, the equivalent `numpy` syntax would be:

```
output[t_ind] = 2*vmax - output[t_ind]
```

Also, you can achieve the same thing using Boolean operators.  MATLAB also has this supported, and so if you want to translate between the two, Boolean (or `logical` in the MATLAB universe) is the better way to go:

```
output[output > vmax] = 2*vmax - output[output > vmax]
```

For the 2D case, you don't use `np.flatnonzero`.  Use [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) instead:

```
t_ind = np.where(output > v_max)
output[t_ind] = 2*vmax - output[t_ind]
```

`t_ind` will return a tuple of `numpy` arrays where the first element gives you the row locations and the second element gives you the column locations of those values that satisfied the Boolean condition that is placed into `np.where`.

As a small note, the case for Boolean indexing still applies to any dimensions of the matrix you desire.  However, `np.flatnonzero` would compute **row-major** indices of those points that satisfy the input condition into `np.flatnonzero`.  The reason why you're getting an error is because you are trying to use row-major indices to access a 2D array.  Though linear indexing is supported in Python, this is not supported in `numpy` - you would have to access each dimension independently to do this indexing, which is what specifying `t_ind` as the input indexes into `output` would be doing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @rayryeng, I'm testing this in my data and I'll let you know.

Comment: @alexandrejaguar - No problem.  I've also updated my answer for the 2D case as you didn't mention that in your initial problem statement

Comment: Awesome @rayryeng, very Pythonic. Learned a lot on this. Thanks also Bi Rico for your kind help.

Comment: @alexandrejaguar - No problem at all. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Numpy supports both boolean indexing and multi-dimensional indexing so you don't need to jump through all those hoops, here are two ways to get what you want:

```
# The setup
import numpy as np
a = np.random.random((3, 4))
vmax = 1.2
output = np.zeros(a.shape, a.dtype)

# Method one, use a boolean array to index
mask = a > .5
output[mask] = 2 * vmax - a[mask]

# Method tow, use indices to index.
t_ind = np.nonzero(a > .5)
output[t_ind] = 2 * vmax - a[t_ind]
```